# HTML5 video: Recognize a new source

Tags: jquery, html, dom, html5-video

I'm attempting to create a HTML5 video player that will play a new video automatically once the current video has ended.

Here is my current code so far (http://jsfiddle.net/fFuez/1/):

```
<video autobuffer controls width="500" id="player">
   <source src="http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/763_sammyJSIntro/trailer_test.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="source">
</video>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () { 

      $("#player").bind("ended", function() {
        alert("Finshed, play new video now...");
        $('#source').attr('src', 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4'); 
      });

    });  
</script>
```

The ended event is firing (according to the `alert();`) but the new file does't seem to be recognized by the player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<source>` element and add the `src` attribute directly on the `<video>` tag. You only need `<source>` elements when there are more than one source. Then, change the `src` of the `<video>` and it should work just fine.

If you need to support more filetypes (OGG video for Firefox, for example), then you should use the `canPlayType()` method to detect which `src` extension is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#player`, not `#source`